# Инициализаторы в Java

Tags: java, инициализация

Зачем в Java использовать инициализаторы, если можно просто сразу присвоить переменной значение "по-умолчанию"?

Comment: читали документацию про инициализаторы? Там есть примеры? Разве в инициализаторах можно только переменным значения присваивать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> если можно просто сразу присвоить переменной значение "по-умолчанию"

Всё верно. Но иногда это стартовое значение "по умолчанию" вычисляется с помощью сложной логики, которую в один оператор не загонишь.